# Can a non Jew bake bread on Pesach for a Jew to use after Pesach?

Tags: halacha, passover, cooking-bishul, chametz-leaven, amira-leakum

In relation to [If the last day of Passover is Friday, may I eat chametz on the Shabbat right after?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/is-it-possible-to-have-chometz-on-the-shabbos-directly-after-pesach), is there any problem if a non Jew bakes bread on Pesach (the Jew(s) did not ask him and can do without bread) to give or sell to a Jew after Pesach is over?

If a gentile can sell/give to a Jew bread he made on the last day of Pesach, can he give bread to a Jew on friday night motzei Pesach for the sake of Shabbos? (Note: this can only happen in Eretz Yisrael because of the fixed calendar.)

Comment: You're asking from a 'maaseh pesach' sort of perspective?

Comment: I assume there's no problem, as I've never heard of an injunction against buying packaged bread (Wonder-bread-type (though not Wonder bread itself, which is not certified as kosher)) right after _Pesach_ (unless the owner on _Pesach_ was Jewish, of course). (As always, people should consult their rabbis rather than relying on what they read on this site.)

Comment: Re "if a non Jew bakes bread on Pesach", I assume you mean a bakery? Privately baked _pas akum_ is forbidden anyway, isn't it?

Comment: @msh210 [Not if he bakes it to sell](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.91) as in this question.

Comment: GershonGold, could you clarify why you think it might be a problem?

Comment: In response to my response of "Eat bread at a non Jews house" to "how you can eat Chometz on Shabbos when Pesach ends on Friday" jake requested that I please specify how to get around muktze and/or maaseh shabbos issues.

Comment: @GershonGold Those issues only apply on Shabbat itself. After shabbat it is no longer muktza and after some time it is no longer maaseh shabbat. [I thought](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14266/can-a-non-jew-bake-bread-on-pesach-for-a-jew-to-use-after-pesach#comment26013_14266) you were asking from a pesach perspective.

Comment: https://www.shmuelkunda.com/products/the-longest-pesach.  Part of the premise is that they bought bread from non-Jewish bakers on the day after Pesach (but not any other day of the year) because there was no Jewish baked bread available.  This wouldn't be necessary if some part of the process wasn't done on Pesach itself, otherwise why not just have the Jewish bakers buy flour and bake themselves?

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 opinions in [Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 325,4](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.325.4?lang=he&with=Magen%20Avraham&lang2=he) whether one can benefit from the bread baked by a Gentile bakery when most of its customers are gentile* straight after Shabbos/Yom Tov.

1. There are those who permit since the gentile made the bread in principal for other gentiles for whom prohibition of baking is of no relevance, the bread is *not* considered *Mukze* even though a prohibited melacha (on pesach baking chametz is not for the sake of Yomtov and forbidden) was performed. One may buy *Pas palter* as no kosher bread is available or kosher bread sold to a Gentile and brought back, is of poorer quality as it is old or it has been frozen (Matza is also poor form of bread *lechem Oni*).** This is the opinion of the Rosh (as explained by the [Taz](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.325.4?lang=he&p2=Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.325.3&lang2=he))
2. But some forbid because they consider the wheat *Muktze* when Jewish people  benefit regardless of whether it was baked for Gentiles sake. *Mukze* here means the wheat when Yom Tov commenced was not ready eat as bread without forbidden melacha changes of threshing grinding kneading and baking *shelo letzorech* (not for the sake of Yomtov). This is the opinion of Rabeinu Tam (see Taz)

The Mishna Brura explains when we can rely on the lenient opinion:
(יח) ובשעת הדחק או לצורך מצוה כגון סעודת ברית מילה או לצורך ברכת המוציא יש לסמוך על המתירים
- כגון שדר בכפר יחידי שא"א לשאול פת מחבירו [אחרונים]:
 A "situation of need" for example if he lives in a place where he has no bread available and he cannot borrow bread from his Jewish friend** he can rely on the lenient opinion.

So if anyone Jewish in a Non-Jewish Town cannot find Matza (which is also staple diet like bread) left over from Pesach (after asking their neighbors) they can rely on the lenient opinion and buy bread from the Gentile Bakery straight after Yomtov ends.

This would **not** apply for example to an arab (gentile) bakery (Supervised ingredients) in Israel where most of his customers that he is baking for on Motzei Pesach would be Jewish. So if the arab made bread in a bakery en-masse on the 7th day Pesach (in Israel) for Motzei Yomtov on Shabbos (even though there is no *Pas Yisroel* bread available and kosher ingredients are used), he is mostly making it for the sake of the Jews so this is *Amira leakum** and forbidden (even from an existing flame which the Jew lit). And if a Jew asked a gentile to specifically make him bread privately for *Motzei Yomtov* this is privately baked and completely forbidden to eat even during the year on *chol* days. ***

I think the only permitted way in Israel of eating bread on Shabbos on Motzei Yom Tov, is to eat older leftover Bread that an arab gives to him  (because then its baked by a Gentile on chol Hamoed for the sake of gentiles) but one would pay only after Shabbos. (this is theoretical, I am not aware of any Hechsher on arab owned bakery in Israel where this happens).

---

{*source Mishna Machshirin 2,5: עיר שישראל וגויים דרין בתוכה, והיה בה מרחץ מרחצת בשבת--אם רוב גויים, רוחץ מיד; אם רוב ישראל, ימתין כדי שייחמו חמין; מחצה למחצה, ימתין כדי שייחמו חמין
 i.e if their are more gentiles than Jews in that town one may use a bath house straight after shabbos, as it was heated up for the Gentiles sake. But when their are more Jews than non Jews the Bath house owner is lighting the fire for mainly the Jews and it is prohibited to derive benefit from this because of Amira leakum.

**source - Shulchan Aruch Yoreh Dea 112,2
יש מקומות שמקילין בדבר ולוקחים פת מנחתום העובד כוכבים, במקום שאין שם נחתום ישראל, מפני שהיא שעת הדחק. (וי"א דאפילו במקום שפת ישראל מצוי, שרי) (ב"י לדעת המרדכי וסמ"ק והג"א ומהרי"א ואו"ה ריש כלל מ"ד).
 Note that the rema would hold that *Pas Palter* - bread baked en masse is permitted even where good kosher bread is available.

*** cont. SA YD 112,2אבל פת של בעלי בתים, אין שם מי שמורה בה להקל, שעיקר הגזירה משום חתנות, ואם יאכל פת בעלי בתים יבא לסעוד אצלם.}