# When is it permitted to eat hametz when Pessach ends on Erev Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, passover, chametz-leaven

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to eat chometz on the shabbos directly after Pesach?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/is-it-possible-to-eat-chometz-on-the-shabbos-directly-after-pesach)

This year Pessach in Israel ends on Erev Shabbat.  Is it necessary to wait for Motza'ei Shabbat before eating hametz, or is it permissible to eat hametz once the Hag Sheni ends?

These are the potential problems I see:

- Hametz cannot be purchased or cooked between Motza'ei Hag and Motza'ei Shabbat, so you cannot have any *fresh* hametz.  Is there any way to prepare hametz that isn't forbidden on Shabbat?
- Any hametz you might have lying around is either hametz she'avar alav ha'pesach (and thus forbidden) or hametz that was sold to a gentile.  Is it possible to stipulate that the sale ends on Shabbat?

Assuming that there is a way to obtain hametz that can be legally eaten on Shabbat, is it permissible to eat it?

Comment: @SethJ: You're right.  I searched for a similar question before posting, but the SE search failed to find anything similar (probably due to my different spelling of *hametz* and other words).  I guess the tags did the trick, but only after I posted :-)