# Presents on shabbas

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, transactions, gifts

Can one give a present on shabbas? If the answer is no, then how does it work when one eats by someones house the food one gets is a present (it is changing reshus). Sources please.

Comment: See [here](http://www.tzemachdovid.org/thepracticaltorah/shabbos2.shtml) for some background on gifts on Shabbos.

Answer (score 3):

A kinyan on shabbos is normally forbidden as a protection against the melacha of writing.  Rishonim try to reconcile this with the halacha of one who did not make an eruv tavshilin giving flour to one who did so the latter may cook for him (and that of giving another one's lulav on the first day of sukkos) (See [Beis Yosef 527](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14268&st=&pgnum=395) "uchshem").

The Magen Avraham ([306:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14325&st=&pgnum=112)) sides with the Mordechai that the difference is that the permited cases are necessary for a mitzva.  Shabbos, too, he says is for a mitzva.

So, if one gives a bottle of wine that will be used for that shabbos, it is permitted.  I would think that the recipient is also included in this stipulation and cannot accept a bottle of wine if he knows he will not be using it, regardless of the donors intentions.

Comment: So food from guests falls into what ?

Comment: Same as wine, if the intent on both sides is to use it for that shabbos.

Comment: So taking a piece of kugel to be polite, but I wont eat it, is problematic ?

Comment: I think you're talking about just being a guest at someone's table?  That wouldn't be a present, he is just sharing his food.  It still belongs to the original owner.