# Making a kinyan on hefker items on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, transactions

**Is it possible to take possession (make a *kinyan*) of items which are *hefker* (ownerless) on Shabbat?**

I know that business transactions are prohibited, but i'm unsure whether this applies to any *kinyan*, or just where it was owned by someone. I also read that you cannot make something *hefker* on Shabbat, but nothing about taking something that's *hefker*.

This came up over a silly idea of making some *chametz* *hefker*, and taking possession of it on Shabbat, after Pesach has ended in Israel, and consequently being able to eat the *chametz*.

Comment: Related to the example case: [If the last day of Passover is Friday, may I eat chametz on the Shabbat right after?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14263/5151)

Comment: Making *chametz hefker* with the intention of claiming it back after *pesach* would not be a valid "*biur*"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One may make a *kinyan* on *hefker* items on *shabbos* (*[R' Akiva Eiger 339:6 s.v. משום מקח וממכר](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1618)*, *[Aishel Avraham 371:7](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x2340)*), provided that he does so in a way that is not evident to people that he's trying to make a *kinyan* (*[Shmiras Shabbos Kihilchoso 29:32](http://ph.yhb.org.il/plus/01-22-04-05/)*).