# Is this a valid method to be able to eat chametz on Shabbat after Pesach in Israel?

Tags: shabbat, gentiles, passover, chametz-leaven

This year (and next) in Israel, Shabbat immediately follows the last day of Pesach. Of course, the chametz that people sold has not been bought back, but, as it is no longer Pesach, one can eat chametz.

If one wanted to eat chametz on that Shabbat, can one pre-arrange for the Gentile to whom the Jew's chametz had been sold to come to his home, take his chametz (it now belongs to the Gentile) eat lunch at the Jew's home and just share some of that chametz with the Jew?

There are obviously no chametz issues. However, are there any other issues that I may have overlooked such as benefiting from the Gentile's work; *Amira Lenachri* or something else?

Comment: Possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14263/759

Comment: We plan to eat kitniot, but hametz raises practical questions of changing the dishes on shabbat (which is not shabbas-dik) or eating on paper plates (which is not shabbas-dik either)

Comment: @mbloch is not having available delicious food shabbos-dik?

Comment: @mbloch So, a few of your dishes will become chometz. Buy new ones next year. If the food is cold ... you may not even need to do that.

Comment: @DanF Ha! I can see you haven't met Mrs. Bloch :->

Comment: @mbloch If she (or you) worked with Mr. Falk in Washington Heights, I probably have! Even if not, I've met plenty of Mrs. Bloch's and "worse" in my life :-( I'll let you handle **this** Mrs. Bloch. Stick to paper and when she sees that she doesn't have to wash dishes on Shabbat, she and you might have an easier time.