# In Israel, what do you do if Isru Chag of Pesach is on Shabbat?

Tags: shabbat, passover, eretz-yisrael, transactions, chametz-leaven

In Israel, if Isru Chag of Pesach is on Shabbat, when do people reacquire their chametz that they sold on Pesach? Do they acquire it retroactively after the holiday is over, OR do they not acquire it until after Shabbat is over?

For example this year (2012, 5772):
The last day of Pesach is on a Friday, and Isru Chag (the day after the holiday) is on Shabbat.

I know of this question: [If the last day of Passover is Friday, may I eat chametz on the Shabbat right after?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14263/719), but my question here involves chametz that is one's own house and was sold over Pesach.

Comment: Naftali, I know you state that you are aware of the other question, and that you are asking a (slightly) different question, but I believe it is a subset (and a clearer version) of the other. Mods, can you merge the two somehow without doing too much damage to either?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to eat chometz on the shabbos directly after Pesach?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14263/is-it-possible-to-eat-chometz-on-the-shabbos-directly-after-pesach)

Comment: Perhaps someone can merge these two together.

Comment: The other questions was "how to eat _chametz_"; this one his "how to reacquire the _chametz_ you sold". I'm taking the liberty of editing this one to not mention eating, and IMO they are distinct enough to both remain open.

Comment: Calendrically and geographically related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9848

Answer (score 2):

Per the Yalkut Yosef 448:5

It is permitted to eat Chometz on a Shabbos which is immediately after Sheviyi Shel Pesach - there is no Muktza involved, and you if it was sold to the non Jew according to Halacha you may eat it on the day of Shabbos immediately after Sheviyi Shel Pesach. However you have to be extra careful not to take the chometz on Sheviyi Shel Pesach since then you will be prohibited to eat it since you have done Baal Yiro'eh U'Baal Yimotzei. (Yechave Daas 2 Siman 64, Yabia Omer Orach Chaim 9 Siman 46)

> מותר לאכול חמץ בשבת שלאחר שביעי של פסח, ואין בזה איסור משום מוקצה, וכן
>   חמץ שנמכר לגוי כהלכה, מותר לאוכלו ביום שבת שלאחר שביעי של פסח, ולא
>   אמרינן מיגו דאיתקצאי בבין השמשות במוקצה מחמת יום שעבר. ובלבד שלא יטול
>   מהחמץ בעצם יום השביעי של פסח, שאם כן הרי הוא עובר עליו בבל יראה ובבל
>   ימצא. וגם הוא חמץ של ישראל שעבר עליו הפסח שאסור בהנאה.

Comment: Gershon, I personally don't see how this is not a duplicate of the other question Naftali linked in his question, but in any event, you should probably cross-post this answer there as well, as it would provide a clear source in place of the speculation going on there. Btw, does R' 'Ovadiah Yosef give a source for his reasoning? (I'm unable to look it up right now.)

Comment: Interesting Yalkut Yosef...how does he resolve the issue of engaging in commerce on shabbos?  This does not seem to be normative practice.  I have not heard anyone here in Israel this year, suggest this method for eating chametz this motze pesach.